# Warum heißt es "hat gebrannt" statt "ist gebrannt"?

Tags: verb, past-participle, auxiliary-verb, sein-or-haben

Ich dachte, dass alle intransitive Verben als Partizip II mit "sein" zu kombinieren sind. Trotzdem schreibt man "Das Haus hat gebrannt" statt "Das haus ist gebrannt". Warum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Unterscheidung zwischen transitiv und intransitiv ist leider überhaupt nicht hilfreich, da die Verben sich nicht an so eine einfache Regel halten.

Das Verb *brennen* gibt es wie viele andere Verben auch in beiden Varianten, und das Perfekt wird jeweils mit *haben* gebildet:

> Er brennt **den Schnaps** aus Trester. (Präsens Aktiv transitiv)
>
> Er hat **den Schnaps** aus Trester gebrannt. (Perfekt Aktiv transitiv)
>
> Dieser Schnaps brennt in der Kehle. (Präsens Aktiv intransitiv)
>
> Dieser Schnaps hat in der Kehle gebrannt. (Perfekt Aktiv intransitiv)

Das Hilfsverb *sein* wird bei solchen Verben zur Bildung des Zustandspassivs verwendet:

> Dieser Schnaps ist aus Trester gebrannt. (Präsens Zustandspassiv)
>
> Dieser Schnaps wird aus Trester gebrannt. (Präsens Vorgangspassiv)

---

Viele eigentlich als intransitiv bekannte Verben können ebenfalls mit einem Akkusativobjekt stehen – allerdings ergeben nur wenige Objekte einen Sinn, z.B. dieses:

> Ich gehe **eine Abkürzung**. (Präsens Aktiv transitiv)

Das Perfekt wird in der transitiven Variante mit *sein* gebildet und es gibt dann kein Zustandspassiv.

> Ich bin **die Abkürzung** gegangen. (Perfekt Aktiv transitiv)
>
> Die Abkürzung wird gegangen. (Präsens Vorgangspassiv)

In der intransitiven Variante sind hingegen beide Deutungen möglich:

> Sie ist gegangen. (Perfekt Aktiv intransitiv **oder** Präsens Zustandspassiv)

Comment: (Diese ganze Unterscheidung zwischen transitiven und intransitiven Verben ist mir überhaupt das erste mal im Englischunterricht begegnet. Sie nützt einem im Deutschen einfach nichts.)

Comment: Ich finde es irreführend, Ausnahmen wie *den Weg gegangen sein* als Argument dafür zu benutzen, daß es keinen Zusammenhang zwischen Transitivität und Wahl des Perfekthilfsverbs gäbe: *Der Ball ist gerollt*, aber *er hat den Ball gerollt* usw. Oder, aus [dieser Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/53841/35111): *Die Zeit ist genaht*, aber *die Zeit hat sich genaht*.

Comment: Das schrieb ich auch nicht, sondern, *Die Unterscheidung zwischen transitiv und intransitiv ist leider überhaupt nicht hilfreich, da die Verben sich nicht an so eine einfache Regel halten.* – Im Übrigen gilt der Gegenbeweis als starker Hinweis dafür, dass eine bestehende Theorie zu einfach ist.

Comment: Aber ein Lerner, der sich einprägt, daß transitive Verben das Perfekt mit *haben* bilden und sich dann vielleicht noch ein paar Ausnahmen merkt, hat doch weniger Arbeit als einer, der davon ausgeht, daß man bei jedem transitiven Verb nachschlagen muß, ob es das Perfekt mit *sein* oder mit *haben* bildet?

Comment: Welche Verben sind denn im Deutschen intransitiv? **Es sind andere** als z.B. im Englischen. Man müsste diese Kategorie also so oder so lernen, und verwirrt sich dabei anhand der eigenen Muttersprache noch selbst. Dazu kommt noch, dass *intransitiv* im Deutschen ja nur heißt, dass es kein Akkusativobjekt gibt. Und nicht wie z.B. im Englischen, dass es gar kein Objekt gibt. Auch da nützt einem diese Unterscheidung also nichts. Man muss sich sowieso merken, mit welchen Objektfällen jedes einzelne Verb steht.

Comment: Fair enough, aber die Regel hilft immerhin in den Fällen, in denen man einen Beispielsatz vor Augen hat (wie *der Schnapps brennt in der Kehle* oder *er brennt seinen eigenen Schnaps*, oder die Beispiele mit *nahen*).

Comment: Ich denke, dass man solche Feinheiten wie die Objektfälle und sein-Perfekt am besten durch Nachäffen lernt. Viele Beispiele lesen und irgendwann sitzt das einfach.

Comment: Bemerkenswert scheint mir hier noch zu sein, dass _etw. ist verbrannt_ mit _sein_ gebildet wird.

Comment: Das ist doch wieder Zustandspassiv. Perfekt: *Er hat die Papiere verbrannt.*

Answer (score 3):

Laut [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/brennen) ist das Hilfsverb von [brennen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/brennen) im Perfekt II (*gebrannt*) in der Tat *haben*. Das entspricht auch dem normalen Sprachgebrauch.

Es ist keine allgemeine Regel, dass alle intransitiven Verben im Perfekt mit dem Hilfsverb *sein* gebildet werden. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfekt_im_Deutschen#Perfekt_mit_%E2%80%9Ehaben%E2%80%9C_oder_%E2%80%9Esein%E2%80%9C) erklärt dazu

> Mit dem Hilfsverb „sein“ wird das Perfekt einer Gruppe von intransitiven oder intransitiv benutzten Verben gebildet, die eine *Ortsänderung* („von A nach B“: kommen, gehen, fahren, springen …) ausdrücken. Diese Verben werden als *Bewegungsverben* bezeichnet. Beispiel: „Ich *bin* mit dem Auto gefahren“ – aber: „Ich *habe* dich gefahren.“ Auch eine Gruppe von Verben, die eine *Zustandsänderung* (Übergang von einem Zustand in einen anderen) ausdrücken (aufwachen, sterben, verwelken), bilden das Perfekt mit „sein“. Außerdem bilden die Verben *sein*, *werden* und *bleiben* das Perfekt mit „sein“. Bei den transitiven Verben im [Passiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aktiv_und_Passiv_im_Deutschen) wird das Perfekt ebenfalls mit „sein“ in Verbindung mit der Partizipform „worden“ gebildet.

*Brennen* in dieser Bedeutung gehört nicht zu diesen Gruppen. Mit *sein* nähme man eher an, es handele sich nicht um einen Hausbrand, sondern das Haus bestünde vielleicht aus gebrannten [Ziegeln](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauerziegel). Oder der [Hausschnaps](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brennen_(Spirituosen)) ist gebrannt.

Comment: Oh, und der Schnaps *hat* auch ziemlich gebrannt. Das wäre mehr elaboration wert?

Comment: @LangLangC Bezieht sich das nun auf *brennen* nach Anzünden oder nach Trinken (im Hals)? Ich verweise mit dem Link auf das Brennen von Spirituosen, d. h. zur Herstellung.

Comment: Das isses ja. TAL hat Schnaps gebrannt. Als er fertig war, war der Schnaps gebrannt. Als ich ihn dann trinken musste, als ich Brand hatte, hat der Schnaps wieder im Hals gebrannt. It's a dance.

Comment: @LangLangC Weil sich die Bedeutung von *gebrannt* jedes Mal ändert. In der Frage geht es aber um ein brennendes Haus und da ist es *haben*. Die Hinweise auf gebrannte Ziegel und gebrannten Schnaps habe ich nur gebracht, weil man durchaus auch auf *gebrannt* mit *sein* stoßen kann. Das sind aber nur Hinweise, denn für die Klärung der Frage sind sie nicht wirklich bedeutsam.

Comment: Ich frag ja nur nach dem Schnaps, weil mit der Parallele in Wortbildung und Bedeutung man sich auch mit dem Getränk darüber trösten könnte, wo die Schuld zu suchen sei, oder ob das Haus nu gebrannt *hat,* oder abgebrannt *ist.*