# Two second-person pronouns in the first sentence of the dedication from "Faust"

Tags: word-usage, pronoun

The first sentence of the *Zueignung* in the beginning of Goethe's *Faust, Eine Tragödie* reads thus:

> Ihr naht euch wieder, schwankende Gestalten!

I am interpreting this as something along the lines of "Again you come, shifting forms!" I'm operating under the notion that *euch* is here being used as some manner of second-person plural pronoun, possibly the Dative.

That leaves me with two questions:
1. What is the specific grammatical classification of this use of *euch*
2. If I am right about what it is, why is a second pronoun being employed for the same entities for an intransitive behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb *nahen* takes an optional dative object which is the "receiver" of the subject.

> Ein Zug naht.
>
> Ein Zug naht der Gruppe.

Suppose you and your friends are up to cross rails. Someone shouts:

> Vorsicht! Ein Zug naht euch!

Though, in modern German, *nahen* is replaced by *sich nähern* almost always.

> Vorsicht! Ein Zug nähert sich euch!

In those examples *euch* is a personal pronoun.

---

In your example

> Ihr naht euch wieder.

that *euch* is a reflexive pronoun. It just doubles *ihr* as the dative object of *nahen* is optional.

We can only guess it's used for effect. It's not a train which may hit them, but *ihr*, they themselves. Or each other.

(Remember you cannot tell personal pronouns from reflexive pronouns in German apart from the 3rd person *sich*.)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! It must be for effect as you've said; it certainly fits the context well, and isn't that different from the English phenomenon of doubling pronouns for emphasis.

Comment: This is quite wrong. "Sich nahen" is **not** a device for emphasis. It is only possible here because "nahen" is an (optionally) reflexive verb to begin with. You could not write e.g. "sich radfahren" in place of "radfahren" just for emphasis - not even Goethe could.

Comment: I do not assume that it was categorically an emphatic, just that it made sense in *this* context given the details Janka provided about nahen already. However, if you have an alternate interpretation of the use of "euch" in this particular sentence, I would be interested to hear it.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? Without knowing any other examples I would just have assumed that *nahen* is used in exactly the same way as modern *nähern*.

Comment: *Das Ende naht (uns).* aber nicht *Das Ende nähert (uns).*, sondern *Das Ende nähert **sich** (uns).*